# Confused about use of rails 4 or 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What are some good changes in Rails 5.
I want to switch from rails 4 to rails 5.
Is it a god idea or i should stick with rails 4.
I know rails 5 is on his way and not launched yet but i am still curious to know about upcoming changes in it.

Comment: http://www.techoalien.com/2015/06/changes-in-rails-5.html

Answer (score 1):

Some things that are new in Rails 5:
- rails instead of rake command, e.g.

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

will become

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

- Rails will only work with Ruby 2.2.1+

There will be other performance enhancing additions. 
You can read more here: http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-new-rails-5/

I recommend you work with Rails 4x until Rails 5 is fully established.

Comment: I found one http://www.techoalien.com/2015/06/changes-in-rails-5.html